# Is there any service registry and discovery framework for the WCF services?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, soa, microservices

There are many service registry and discovery framework out. i.g. Eureka, SmarkStack, Zookeeper, Doozer etc. I have searched a lot for wcf service registry and discovery framework for the WCF SOAP services on Windows. We are building a high frequency trading application (Windows application) where performance is the key. Is there any framework out to help us running multiple instances of the services across machines dynamically?

Or any related pointers?

Thanks

Comment: if u host ur wcf on iis, the built-in wsdl should just work by itself right out-of-the-box.

Comment: We do need more control over services. Moreover we need high availability, distributed and data center aware control over services